# How to get nested JSON response in android app using Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have this JSON response:

```
    {
    Exam_Name:[
     {
        Exam_1:[
            {
                id:"1",
                option_a:"php",
                option_b:"css",
                option_c:"java",
            },
            {
                id:"2",
                option_a:"mysql",
                option_b:"sqlite",
                option_c:"oracle",
            },
            {
                id:"3",
                option_a:"html",
                option_b:"python",
                option_c:"javascript",
            }
        ],
        
        Exam_2:[
            {
                id:"1",
                option_a:"a",
                option_b:"b",
                option_c:"c",
            },
            {
                id:"2",
                option_a:"1",
                option_b:"2",
                option_c:"3",
            },
            {
                id:"3",
                option_a:"A",
                option_b:"B",
                option_c:"C",
            }
        ],
        Exam_3:[
            {
                id:"1",
                option_a:"a1",
                option_b:"b1",
                option_c:"c1",
            },
            {
                id:"2",
                option_a:"a2",
                option_b:"b2",
                option_c:"c2",
            },
            {
                id:"3",
                option_a:"A1",
                option_b:"B1",
                option_c:"C1",
            }
        ]
     }
    
    ]
}
```

I am able to get data when I am using `SerializedName` but I want to know how can I get without `SerializedName` because I have hundreds of Exam numbers and I can't create `SerializedName` for all.

Below I have created the initial model class for inner objects:

```
    public class ModelClass implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("option_a")
    @Expose
    private String option_a;

    @SerializedName("option_b")
    @Expose
    private String option_b;

    @SerializedName("option_c")
    @Expose
    private String option_c;

    public ModelClass(int id, String option_a, String option_b, String option_c) {
        this.id = id;
        this.option_a = option_a;
        this.option_b = option_b;
        this.option_c = option_c;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getOption_a() {
        return option_a;
    }

    public String getOption_b() {
        return option_b;
    }

    public String getOption_c() {
        return option_c;
    }
}
```

and plz suggest me a way to call Exam_1, Exam_2, Exam_3...... without any `SerializedName`. Thank you.

Comment: Who is creating the API? Because it's bad. Why not use an array of `Exam` object rather than an object containing keys `Exam_1`, `_2` and so on. Just return an array, deserialize in a list and voila, you can have hundreds of Exams with 0 problems. Contact your API provider. Why do I have a strong feeling it's you?

Comment: ok, it was me....bcz I not have knowledge of making APIs....can you plz modify the structure of this API so that i can call it without any problem.

Comment: I knew it :-) You need to return an array of values, rather than an object containing dozens of keys. You need to learn some programming basics there, friend. I don't think I can help you any more than I have, honestly.